# Prototype.js error on a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am getting error on following function:

```
Event.observe(window, "load", function () {    
    if ($("question") && $("question").type.toLowerCase() == "textarea") {
        Event.observe("question", "keyup", function () {
            var _4 = $F("question");
            if (_4.length > 255) {
                $("question").value = _4.substring(0, 255);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

type is null or not an object.

in prototype.js it gives error on:

```
   var respondersForEvent = registry.get(eventName);
    if (Object.isUndefined(respondersForEvent)) {
      respondersForEvent = [];
      registry.set(eventName, respondersForEvent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a $(document).ready(). I believe the window load event will fire before all the DOM nodes are created.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this in code? I am really new to programming that would help. Thanks

Comment: If you are using Prototype and not Jquery (you're obviously loading Prototype, but the question is tagged Jquery, so it's not clear...and not wise to run both simultaneously), $(document).ready won't work.  Try this instead if you need a dom loader with Prototype:  http://newrelease.co.za/web-applications/jquery-documentready-and-the-prototype-equivalent/  If you are running both, then you would likely be getting errors anyways since Prototype would reserve the $ operator.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, I have to support a legacy app that uses both jQuery and Prototype.  If my javascript throws nearly any error, Firebug and Chrome will report it as an error in Prototype.js.  Since I've almost completely undone Prototype, it's never the real problem.

In the circumstances, I assume that it's NEVER prototype and start debugging my own code that's fired by this page.